# Invoke contract from one account and pay gas using another account

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-invocation

Is it possible to invoke a contract method from a given account (that I own) and pay for the gas using a different account (that I also own)? Concretely I'm trying to transfer ECR20 tokens from an account that doesn't have any Ether, and I was hoping to do this without having to transfer Ether to it to pay for the transaction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only be possible if the second address is allowed to transfer tokens from the first address. In other words the first address must have called the token contract *approve* operation before (which requires paying for gas obviously anyway).

AFAIK some changes in the direction that would allow contracts to pay for their own gas are proposed for Metropolis (see EIP86).